# MPI - Distributed Workers Queue

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads, mpi, task-queue

I am in the process of developing a parallel sudoku solving algorithm by traversing a permutation tree breadth-first.

I have a root process which has a queue of puzzle instances.
The root process allows for worker processes to enqueue() and dequeue() instances of the puzzle.

I am fairly new to MPI so please let me know if this approach is feasible.

The master process will have two threads constantly running

```
MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided)
if(rank == 0){
    push(puzzle);

    pthread_t dequeue_listener, enqueue_listener;
    pthread_create(&dequeue_listener, NULL, dequeue_listen, NULL);
    pthread_create(&enqueue_listener, NULL, enqueue_listen, NULL);
}
```

one listening for enqueue requests, the other for dequeue requests

```
void *dequeue_listen(){
    while(1)
        MPI_Ssend(pop(), SIZE, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void *enqueue_listen(){
     while(1){
         int *buffer = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
         MPI_Recv(buffer, SIZE, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
         push(buffer);
     }
}
```

pop() and push() are both methods performed by the master node to interact with the queue directly.

the worker processes will do something as follows (note, I trimmed the code for simplicity)

```
while(!is_empty(queue) && !solution_found){
    dequeue();
    process_children_and_check_for_solution();
    enqueue(children);
}
```

with their API as follows:

```
int *dequeue(){
    int *puzzle = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    MPI_Recv(puzzle, SIZE, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    return puzzle;
}

void enqueue(int *puzzle){
    MPI_Ssend(puzzle, SIZE, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
}
```

In theory, this makes a lot of sense to me and can be used in many applications involving a worker queue.
However.. I consistently get `MPI_fatal` errors in either `MPI_Recv` or `MPI_Ssend` calls from the root process. I can always successfully `dequeue()` the first element (tested with a simple `print_puzzle()` method).

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm kind of confused here: you say that there are workers (with a "s", so multiple of them), but your sending and receiving loops on the master are only communicating with process of rank 1. Is that a typo? And if it is a typo, how do you manage the multiplicity of workers?

Comment: You are correct. As of now, the code only supports a single worker. My plan was to get that working and then begin managing additional workers.

Comment: Did you check the level of multi-threading your MPI library supports? I see you use `MPI_Init_thread()` but I don't see you checking whether `provided` is as good as the requested `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`...

Comment: Good point. MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE = 3, provided = 2.

Comment: Well, there you go! You definitely need `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` so if your library cannot provide it to you, there's no other choice (with your design) than changing of MPI library.

Comment: Thank you! 
Any insights with altering the design? I am running this code on servers which I do not have admin access. Is there no way of _pinging_ the master node without having it constantly listening?

Comment: I honestly don't see the point of using a multi-threaded approach in the first place: it'll be complex to manage and won't make the thing more effective. Just do the send/receive on the master in a single loop after a first round of initial distribution to all workers. Using a receive with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` and then sending back to whoever was sending to you will do just fine. AAMOF, I did exactly that for parallelising a sudoku grand challenge a few years ago, and it worked marvellously well.